# Get request headers (cookies) in routingdsl in play framework for java

Tags: java, mocking, playframework-2.0

I am still learning Play framework for Java. I am trying to create a test case where I am mocking server. In there, I am defining url and response using RoutingDSL. However, I can't seem to find any way to access request headers (actually I am trying to see if client is sending proper cookies).
Here is the snippet of code:

```
   server = Server.forRouter(20000, components -> 
       RoutingDsl.fromComponents(components)
       .GET("/demo").routeTo(() -> 
           // Here I need something to get request headers or cookies
           new Result(HttpStatus.SEE_OTHER_303)).build());
```

**Solution:**
After looking through the documentation (it was mentioned briefly here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaRoutingDsl):

> Since you will be implementing actions, you may want to import the
>   static methods from Controller, which includes factory methods for
>   creating results, accessing the request, response and session.

Basically, idea was to use static methods from `play.mvc.Controller` class, where that information is held:

```
   server = Server.forRouter(20000, components -> 
       RoutingDsl.fromComponents(components)
       .GET("/demo").routeTo(() -> 
           doSomethingWithRequest(play.mvc.Controller.request())
           new Result(HttpStatus.SEE_OTHER_303)).build());
```

Comment: This usage of statics is a bit strange to me, but maybe it is a normal idiom in Play framework (as it is based on Scala). As I know, in Java you should not rely that statics will hold information that is thread specific, as they will all be updated by JVM with singular value at some point (unless you state that is volatile in which case, all threads will see the update immediately). In other words, all threads will have same results in statics. Maybe, Play is doing something differently how he gets request data (map that has keys that are Thread names?)